# File Association in Xamarin Forms (Android not working)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The application needs to receive XML Files from web downloads as well as Mail attachments.
On iOS everything is working fine, but on Android the File Association isn't working. The program is running fine, but when trying to open XML files Android says "cannot open file"

I tried different MemeTypes, DataShemes and Actions but none are working.

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTask,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView},
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },
    DataScheme = "file",
    DataHost = "*",
    DataPathPattern = ".*\\.xml",
    DataMimeType = @"application/xaml+xml")]

public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        string action = Intent.Action;
        string type = Intent.Type;

        //If opened to recieve a file
        if (Intent.ActionView.Equals(action) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opened to recieve a file!");
        }

        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

I expect the application to be used for opening & sending .xml files
which will then be handled.

Edit: Link to test Application, where Console shout say "Opened to recieve a file" when it works. https://dracoon.team/#/public/shares-downloads/BMCPjb5XGlWyQArahpnl2x1uoHmBCRv6

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang added link to a testproject download to the question

Comment: Sorry, how to reproduce this question ?

Comment: @JessieZhang start the android simulator and try to open an xml (either from mail or files app) - app should be able to open it due to file association but says it cannot open xml

Comment: Sorry,man , after I run the app on a android device, and tried to open an xml from a email, but the app couldn't open the xml.In other words,there is no automatic association with the xml.

Comment: @JessieZhang exactly thats the problem, I cant get it to work, there should be automatic association with the xml

Comment: I haven't dealt with this before, I'll come back asap if I have any result.

Comment: @JessieZhang thanks alot, will post the solution if I manage to come up with one as well

Answer (score 1):

For the people who are looking for a solution in how to associate your app with `open with...` (which I wasn't able to find a clear answer to this problem). Here is what worked for me:

I'm using Xamarin 16.7

Just like Louis (OP), I was trying the following `IntentFilter`:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView},
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },
    DataScheme = "file",
    DataHost = "*",
    DataPathPattern = ".*\\.txt",
    DataMimeType = @"*/*")]
```

To test the above intent filter, I would go to the default file app, and try to open a txt file, but my app wouldn't show as an option.

Then I changed it to:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, 
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = @"text/plain")]
```

And it worked. The problem was that in `DataScheme`, when trying `open with...`, it wasn't `file`, it was actually `content`.

If you have these kind of problems, make sure the filter is setup correctly.